# NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification doesn't work?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, cloudkit

I'm creating a cloudkit app, and have been trying multiple ways to get the `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification`, but I never am able to get this notification.

I've tried both of these code versions under the delegate `didFinish` and the `viewDidLoad` methods. And I tried calling it from another notification - `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. I also put `import Foundation` at top of files.

Here's the basic code I've tried:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "handleIdentityChanged:",
        name: NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification,
        object: nil)
```

// And this one I tried too from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442035/cloudkit-how-to-access-main-users-attributes/28448502#28448502) on SO:

```
    var localeChangeObserver = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { _ in
        println("The user’s iCloud login changed: should refresh all user data.")
    }
```

Does anyone know how to get this notification to work for only a cloudkit app in swift?  I really just want to detect the iCloud status change and then initiate fetching the `userID` if there's been a change.

Not that I need to access the `ubiquityIdentityToken`, but I was wondering why not store the token and every-time the app starts compare the current token with the one in local storage to see if it's a different account or nil? Therefore, why is getting the notification necessary?

Also, the code for getting the token only seems to work if I turn on "iCloud Documents", which I don't need. Does anyone know the implications of having that turned on for a social app that doesn't need it? And is there another way to get the token without enabling iCloud Documents?

This is the code I used to get token and placed in the delegate `didFinish` method, but only works if iCloud documents is turned on:

```
var token = NSFileManager.defaultManager().ubiquityIdentityToken
    println("token is \(token!)")
```

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, when I sign out of iCloud, my app is killed. So there seems not really to be a need to receive a `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification`. Like you have said, it seems to be sufficient to compare the current token to the saved token.

On the Apple TV though, my app was not killed when I logged out of iCloud. Here I had noticed the notification was not fired, like you described. Since the app is not killed, a notification would be in order. (Did Apple forget to kill apps on Apple TV when iCloud account is changed?)

With Apple TV there is no iCloud documents container available (unless I explicitly share one from an iOS app). I found that on the dev center website, for the app identifier, iCloud was shown as "Configurable" and not "Enabled" if no document container was selected. I wonder if this has an effect on receiving notifications.

Both on the Apple TV and iOS, I can also confirm that the iCloud token is `nil` when not using documents (here: key-value-store only). Now that makes it difficult for Apple TV apps (because the app is not killed on iCloud account change, like on iOS) to detect account changes.

I have just noticed that my Apple TV app does received several `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification` when I log into another iCloud account, to reflect the changes. I guess this is as good as it gets. These notifications come with the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreChangeReasonKey` key in `userInfo`, and a value of `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreAccountChange` indicates the account has changed.

Sorry for not being able to provide a direct solution, maybe it helped to share my experience.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  I ended up giving up on the notification and have not revisited it in a while, so maybe this issue has been fixed by Apple....I recall seeing other posts that complained of not getting this notification as well.  I've never worked with Apple TV, but that sounds fun.  I'm not familiar with the notifications you mentioned at the end, but sounds like it has to do with key value storage, which I've not used yet.  Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 1):

To be notified in iOS when a user logs in or out of iCloud while using your app, use `CKAccountChangedNotification` instead of `NSUbiquityIdentityChanged` notification.

(Longer explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38689094/54423.)