# NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification does not fire with cloud kit

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

This is my current code

```
func applicationDidBecameActive(notification:NSNotification) {

    println("Application is active")

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleIdentityChange:", name: NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

}

func applicationBecameInactive(notification:NSNotification) {

    println("Application is inactive")

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

}

func handleIdentityChange(notification:NSNotification) {

    println("this is working")

    let fileManager = NSFileManager()

    if let token = fileManager.ubiquityIdentityToken {

        println("New token is \(token)")

    }
    else {

        println("User has logged out of iCloud")

    }

}
```

"Application is active" & "Application is inactive" works properly. There is no problem there.

I could not get it fire "This is working". By logging into different iCloud account or logging out of iCloud account.

I tried on simulator & on actual device.

Please help me fix this or suggest alternative method to achieve same goal(change in iCloud account).

Comment: If you want to change the meaning of another user's answer, rather than edit it, please either explain what you think should be changed in the comment on that answer, or add your own answer.

Comment: Try hooking up notification handler on willEnterForeground. didBecomeActive is too late.

Comment: I tried that. It still doesn't work. Thanks for the help but I am now using CKAccountChangeNotification with iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift I have sometimes needed to add `@objc` in front of a func for NSNotificationCenter to find it.

So instead of

`func handleIdentityChange(notification:NSNotification) {`

I'd try

`@objc func handleIdentityChange(notification:NSNotification) {`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933569/nsubiquityidentitydidchangenotification-doesnt-work). I never received a `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` either. In iOS your app gets killed when you change accounts. In tvOS you can use `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreAccountChange`.